# I would like to know how to insert in an Android EditText the value of a SeekBar

Tags: android, android-edittext, seekbar

I tried doing it with this code:

```
et.setText(sb.getProgress());
```

where et is the EditText and sb the SeekBar.
I get this Exception:

> String resource ID #0x65

the last part of the exception changes with the value of the SeekBar.

Comment: try this: et.setText(String.valueOf(sb.getProgress))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
et.setText(""+sb.getProgress());
```

**Reason ::** The Value of sb is int and **you set int to Edittext** And its Create Problem So EditText **getText() and setText() Always in String**

So there Error tells its not String ........

**Many Ways  Convert Integer To String**

```
et.setText(String.valueOf(sb.getProgress()));
et.setText(Integer.toString(sb.getProgress()));
```